# Highcharts mobile (and window) resizing. Axis overlapping

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The following fiddle shows what is happening to my users in mobile when rotating between portrait and landscape.

- On load, the chart shows up as desired.
- Hit 'Step 1', the chart shrinks and is shown as desired.
- Hit 'Step 2', the chart returns to original size, but the vertical axis labels overlap.

http://jsfiddle.net/burchw78/rwb7ms93/

I have tried chart.redraw(), but with no success. Any ideas?

```
$(function() {
    var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            renderTo: 'industrybasicbar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'All Private Industries Expected to Add Jobs by 2024'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Health care and social assistance',   'Professional and business services',   'Trade, transportation, and utilities', 'Leisure and hospitality',  'Manufacturing',    'Construction', 'Local government', 'Financial activities', 'Other services',   'Natural resources and mining', 'Private educational services', 'State government', 'Information',  'Federal government'
    ],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Projected Growth',
            data: [46300,   45700,  36200,  35800,  21100,  17600,  9600,   9100,   8800,   6100,   4700,   2800,   2000,   -1000
    ],
                    negativeColor: 'black'
        }]


});

    $('#resize').click(function () {
        chart.setSize(300, 300);
    });

    $('#resize2').click(function () {
       chart.setSize(500, 300);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a **bug**. I reported it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8510

**Workaround:**

Update `textOverflow` manually:

```
  $('#resize').click(function() {
    chart.setSize(300, 300);
    chart.xAxis[0].update({
      labels: {
        style: {
          textOverflow: 'ellipsis'
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/axhcwrmd/